# How to upgrade from R16B to 17? list_to_binary breaks if there are Chinese characters inside

Tags: erlang

We are using R16B03-1 and trying to upgrade to R17.

`iolist_to_binary` and `list_to_binary` breaks if there are Chinese characters inside.

I googled and found following links to explain the problem.

1. http://www.erlang.org/news/71

> The default encoding of Erlang files has been changed from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. The encoding of XML files has also been changed to UTF-8

2. http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html

> Only if a string contains code points < 256, can it be directly converted to a binary by using i.e. erlang:iolist_to_binary/1 or can be sent directly to a port. If the string contains Unicode characters > 255, an encoding has to be decided upon and the string should be converted to a binary in the preferred encoding using unicode:characters_to_binary/{1,2,3}. Strings are not generally lists of bytes, as they were before Erlang/OTP R13. They are lists of characters. Characters are not generally bytes, they are Unicode code points.

My question is must we modify all `list_to_binary` to `unicode:characters_to_binary`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the following link
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html

> Other Unicode encodings than integers representing codepoints or UTF-8 in binaries are referred to as "external encodings". The ISO-latin-1 encoding is in binaries and lists referred to as latin1-encoding.
>
> It is recommended to only use external encodings for communication with external entities where this is required. When working inside the Erlang/OTP environment, it is recommended to keep binaries in UTF-8 when representing Unicode characters.

It is not required to modify list_to_binary to unicode:characters_to_binary at all places. It is required only those places where it needs to be interfaced with the external world and you are not sure whether the string will be represented with utf8 (Or you are sure that the encoding is not utf8). After the conversion the standard BIFs can be used.

Example: If there is a list having a character [52974].
`list_to_binary([52974]).` gives bad argument exception error.
But once you do the

`A = unicode:characters_to_binary([52974], utf8).
<<"∞╗«"`>>

After the above conversion you can use the built in functions which are faster inside your business logic.

```
B = binary_to_list(A).
"∞╗«"
list_to_binary(B).
<<"∞╗«">>
```